# Why should one set the proxy server to 127.0.0.1 and port 9050

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, ios

I've visited the website of Anonymous, it has suggested to use Tor browser and set the proxy server to 127.0.0.1 and set the port to 9050, I want to ask what is the purpose of this suggestion and what is the benefit of setting it?
Btw I want to ask in ios devices, you can set the proxy of the wifi you connected to, if I set the proxy server and port to 127.0.0.1 and 9050, what will it do for me?

Comment: I've used TOR along side Privoxy to provide a network base proxy server for machines in my network. This way I can use TOR on an IOS device such as iPhone or iPad. It works, its simple to setup. Here are my steps and I hope it helps you.
You can also customize it Set it and forget it --- http://jermsmit.com/my-quick-tor-socks-web-proxy/ - jermal

Answer (score 2):

By default Tor listens on this port. However you of course need to have Tor up and running, else you won't be able to connect anywhere. If you set this proxy and Tor is running on a device it will connect through Tor. If you don't set the proxy your browser (or any other application) won't be using Tor at all. No anonymity will be provided, because Tor might be running, but the application won't be using it.